# Creating A Base View On Snowflake Stored Proc/ Multiple Statements

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, denodo

I was wondering if you could tell me if there was a way to create a base view on snowflake stored procs.

What I am trying to do is:

Run the stored proc
Capture the result of the proc
The Snowflake statments are like these:

```
—–CALLING THE PROC
CALL DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.PROC_NAME(‘Param1’, ‘Param2’, ‘Param3’, ‘Param4’);

—-CAPTURING THE RESULT
SELECT *
FROM table(result_scan(last_query_id(-2)));
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this. Have you tried using a function instead? It gives you similar functionality to procedures, but can be used in slightly different ways. I haven't tried using one in a view, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: Yes, functions in snowflake can be used to create base views in Denodo. But there are a few things functions can't do. I think I need to look into other options. Or I might just change my approach and go the functions route.

Thank you once again @DavidGarrison

Comment: @DavidGarrison - Quick Question (Now that I am sure you are the expert on the subject).. I am noticing we can't create a Denodo base view with query on more than 1 SQL statement, am I right? In which case, I still won't be able to call the proc and access the result set in using RESULT_SCAN(). Am I right on that?

Thank you once again for helping!

Comment: I don't know about Denodo specifically, but there isn't a way to have multiple statements in a view that I know of. A CTE will usually work in most scenarios where you need multiple queries, but that doesn't work with the procedure/result_scan approach. I'll think on it a little more though. Perhaps if I knew more of your specific usecase, I could help suggest alternative approaches.